# Changing text in label make text align not working?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here's the things i have done with my label in runtime:(C#)

```
label.Text = sometext;
label.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

label.Invalidate();
label.Update();
label.Refresh();
label.PerformLayout();
```

And after the window is shown, before this code runs, the default text aligns perfectly in middle center. after this code runs, the text is aligned top left.

The autosize is false for the label.

Now, where did I do wrong?

Update:

I found a partial solution with no idea why to my own question:
Turning "UseCompatibleTextRendering" true would make the text align correctly without any of the 5 lines of codes after text modifying. But this makes no sense. isn't the new text rendering supposed to be better, and old rendering expose me to visual artifacts etc?

Comment: @usar this code runs inside an event. there's a list view, i was going to change the text of the label according to what's selected. the text is changed as expected, but aligned to top left. and none of the code after has made it back to middle center

Comment: I check the above code its work fine for me. this label created it run time or design time

Comment: @Sathish Thanks for the reassurance. i'm using visual studio express 2013, is that the problem? also check my update.

Comment: @usar I would rather believe it's microsoft's fault since that's the only part of MY code that involves this label, but something obvious like this would've made it everywhere in google search result.. sigh~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce your problem, but cannot.  I suggest you modify this simple code to try to reproduce your problem:

```
class FormD : Form {

    Label lb = new Label { Text = "ABCDEFG", Size = new Size(200, 200), TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, BackColor = Color.RosyBrown, UseCompatibleTextRendering = true };

    public FormD() {
        Controls.Add(lb);
    }

    [STAThread]
    static void Main(String[] args) {
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        Form f2 = new FormD();
        Application.Run(f2);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. This code itself did not solve my problem, but you give me a way of nailing down the error. I eventually found the problem was with my string. The string i had was fetched from database, and i need to do a  trim(); for it to work properly. Thanks!